# Pdf not being created by Tex editors

Tags: pdftex, pdf, texmaker

I am a newbie to LaTeX and was trying to form my first document with the code as given below

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Project report}
\end{document}
```

I have TeX Live 2016 installed and have tried using TeXworks and TeXmaker to run the code. I have installed everything correctly and have tried a few `.tex` files which I downloaded from online websites and they seem to work. So I know something is wrong with my code. For the code, TeXmaker just compiles and give me a `"File Not Found"` error and TeXworks doesn't give me an error but nothing happens. I can use a template for my report but I am trying to learn LaTeX so any help would be great. I have also tried solutions mentioned in other questions but they didn't work likely because most of those had some setting issues and mine's something to do with the code I think.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Hint: if you indent the code by 4 spaces it's formatted as such. Have you tried writing anything after the `\begin{document}`? The `\title` macro does not print any text whatsoever, it only *holds* the title. To print the title page, use the command `\maketitle` which will print the contents of `\author`, `\title` and `\date`, the format of the printed title page depends on the class you use.

Comment: The `\title` macro just sets the content of a variable that is used when you call the `\maketitle` macro. It thus prints nothing (and can be written in the preamble). Have a try with`\documentclass[10pt]{article} \title{Project report}\author{Doe, John}
\begin{document}
\maketitle Hello world!
\end{document}`. I suggest you to have a look at [the not so short introdution to LaTeX](http://tug.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf): it will help you climb the learning curve!

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos thanks    `\maketitle`    was what's missing.

Comment: @ebo thanks! I was trying to try what some guy on youtube did maybe I wasn't paying attention but `\maketitle` works well and also thanks for the introduction manual!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\title` command just sets the content of a variable that is used when you call the `\maketitle` macro. (The role of the latter is to format and print the content of `title`, `author`, and `date` variables according to some settings — e.g. the document class, font size, etc.).
*The `\title` command thus prints nothing* (and can be written in the preamble).

To print (or display) the title (and other information), **you need the `\maketitle` command**. Have a try with following [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
   \title{Project report}
   \author{Doe, John}

\begin{document} 
   \maketitle 

   Hello world! 
\end{document}
```